# Passing within components Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, fetch, sanity, next.js13

I can't find a way to successfully pass const SanityData into function Home and when typing console.log(products,bannerData) data to be shown and used inside function Home.

I tried to call SanityData() inside function Home as you can see, but I still receive undefined when I try to {console.log(products,bannerData)} below .

For now I can only see data when typing console.log(products,bannerData) inside const SanityData.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfTMe.png)

I have tried to call SanityData() inside function Home but I receive undefined.

I want to be able to use fetched data from const SanityData() inside my function Home component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because your function `SanityData()` is an async function and that means you have to await the promise.
Also, your return properties of your `SanityData()` function are not automatically passed as props to your Home component, instead you have to extract the props from your async function.
Therefore you can also get rid of the `props` property in your return statement of your async function

Your code could look like this to work:

```js
import "./globals.css";
import { Product, FooterBanner, HeroBanner } from "./components/page";
import { client } from "../lib/client";

const SanityData = async () => {
  const query = '*[_type == "products"]';
  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const bannerQuery = '*_type == "banner"]';
  const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);

  return { products, bannerData };
};

export default async function Home() {
  const { products, bannerData } = await SanityData();

  return (
    <>
      <HeroBanner />
      {bannerData?.map((banner) => banner.name)}
      <div className="products-heading">
        <h2>Best Selling Products</h2>
        <p>Speakers of many variations</p>
      </div>
      <div className="products-container">
        {products?.map((product) => product.name)}
      </div>
      <FooterBanner />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: In order to use those variables from SanityData, firstly I had to map over them and then i could extract wanted name or some text or number.
For example <h2>{bannerData.smallText}<h2/> won't work , but {bannerData?.map((banner) => banner.smallText)} will work.